# MariaDB: group_concat with subquery failing

Tags: subquery, mariadb, group-concat

With the exact same database structure and data on MySQL 5.6.34 (my new dev server) and MariaDB 10.2.8 (my new production server, where I thought I was finally deploying the code today - sigh!), MySQL is working and MariaDB is not. This is code that has been working fine for years on MySQL 5.0.95. I have simplified my query to the minimum example that shows the problem - it seems that `GROUP_CONCAT()` and subqueries do not mix. Here is the query:

```
SELECT person.PersonID,
GROUP_CONCAT(CategoryID ORDER BY CategoryID SEPARATOR ',') AS categories
FROM person LEFT JOIN percat ON person.PersonID=percat.PersonID
WHERE person.PersonID IN (SELECT PersonID FROM action WHERE ActionTypeID=3)
GROUP BY person.PersonID
```

And here is a composite image of screenshots that show the structure of all three tables involved:

[image]

On MySQL, it works fine, as it has worked for years. Here is the result and `EXPLAIN`:

[image: MySQL 5.6.34]

And this is the crazy result I get on MariaDB:

[image]

I don't know the inner workings of the DB engine well enough to follow `EXPLAIN`, but I assume the clue is in there somewhere. I found [this bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12561) that sounds related, but I don't really understand what they're saying about it, and more importantly, what I should do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, apparently it is not quite the same as the one that you have found (because the test case from the mentioned bug report works all right on 10.2.8, and yours, indeed, does not). Please feel free to report a new one at [MariaDB JIRA](http://jira.mariadb.org).

Meanwhile, I think you should be able to work around it by setting

```
optimizer_switch=orderby_uses_equalities=off
```

in your cnf file. It's a newly enabled optimization, obviously not flawless.

---

UPDATE: The bug is now reported as https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13694

Comment: I can't seem to turn if off - apparently I'm doing it wrong. In `/etc/my.cnf`, section `[mysqld]`, I added `optimizer_switch = orderby_uses_equalities=off` (I tried it with and without single quotes - I saw examples on the web of both) and restarted mysqld (which also has weird behavior - it doesn't give my ssh prompt back until I press ^C after waiting awhile). But `SELECT @@optimizer_switch\G` says `orderby_uses_equalities` is still on, and there is no change in the query behavior.

Comment: The section and the line are fine. First, check that your server actually restarts (e.g. by verifying `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'` and/or the error log.) It sounds like the server does not really shut down, then attempts to restart, and begins fighting for the datadir, e.g. for the lock over aria control file or such. If the server indeed restarts, the other possible reason is that this cnf file is not used by your installation. You can put there something distinctive right after the optimizer_switch, e.g. `lock_wait_timeout=42` (or whatever you would recognize), and see if it's picked up.

Comment: Yup, that was it - it had not actually restarted (I was doing the command wrong). Your workaround works like a charm! When I have more time I'll work on simplifying my code, but for now, I can press onward with spinning up my new server, thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug. I would have had to register as a member of JIRA first, and I hadn't gotten around to that yet.

Comment: @OsakaWebbie - Show us the entire `SET` statement.  Perhaps you were using `GLOBAL` when you should have used `SESSION`.

Comment: @RickJames Huh? This is a three-year-old thread, and it doesn't have anything to do with a SET statement (I don't even know what that is). Did you accidentally comment on the wrong thread or something?

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround** This won't answer why there is a difference, but you should add `DISTINCT` to the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

**The "why"** Probably the answer is very deeply rooted in the Optimizers.  There have been a lot of changes since 5.0.  5.6 had a lot of new code; at the same time, MariaDB was forking off into 10.0.  In this forking, the Optimizers were diverging significantly.  10.2 has moved farther forward, but not necessarily in optimizing *this type of query*.

**Improved query** There are several things that could be done to the query.  Some will probably make it faster:

```
SELECT  p.PersonID, 
        ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(pc.CategoryID
                               ORDER BY  CategoryID SEPARATOR ',')
            FROM  percat
            WHERE  PersonID = p.PersonID 
        ) AS categories
    FROM  person
    JOIN  action AS a  ON p.PersonID = a.PersonID
    WHERE  ActionTypeID = 3
    GROUP BY  p.PersonID
```

Transforming the `LEFT JOIN` will probably decrease the load on `GROUP BY`.  Possibly the `GROUP BY` can be removed.

Because of `PRIMARY KEY(PersonID, CategoryID)`, there should be no need for `DISTINCT`.

**Needed index** This "covering index" would speed up things more:  `INDEX(ActionTypeID, PersonID)`.

Comment: Adding DISTINCT only eliminated the repeated CategoryID's - it had no effect on the main problem: I still only get one person record when there should be multiples. As for your idea to optimize by changing the subquery to a join, be aware that the query I shared here is super-simplified - in my real application, the user can combine a variety of search criteria, and I have to programmatically make whatever they choose into a working query. I have not been able to figure out a way to do that without subqueries.

Comment: `GROUP BY PersonID` _causes_ there to be only one row per person.  I guess I don't know what you want.  And your sample output has only one row per person.  Mock up the output you do want.

Comment: There are four people that match the WHERE, so there should be four rows returned. The correct output can be seen in the "On MySQL..." screenshot. I don't know why the first three people are not returned, but that is the main problem.